# How to run a Method by clicking on MudTabPanel in MudBlazor

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I want to manipulate with background-color of Component "MyBox" using Tabs. Background of Component has to be filled with the color, named in Tabs.
One condition: you're not allowed to delete `@bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex"` from code (it's used for other purposes).
I have a method "SetColor", but I don't understand how to run it.
I'll be thankfull for any help.

Index.razor

```
<MudTabs Elevation="0" Outlined="true" @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Red"></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Blue"></MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>

<MyBox colorBox="@colorMe"/>

@code
{
    int activeIndex = 0;
    string colorMe = "";
    
    void SetColor()
    {
        if(activeIndex == 0)
        {
            colorMe = "red";
        } 
        else if(activeIndex == 1)
        {
            colorMe = "blue";
        } 
    }
}
```

MyBox.razor

```
<MudItem Style="@($"background-color:{colorBox}; padding:10px; border:1px solid black")">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum sit praesentium eos impedit. Est delectus non fugiat perferendis, quos et quis fugit iusto laborum esse voluptates sequi harum quo ab.
</MudItem>

 
@code {
  [Parameter]
  public string colorBox {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the `MudTabPanel` Text as colors and store the active index of the panel, then we can assign value of color to `MyBox` by accessing the panel's text by index. This way is better if you are working with a lot of tabs as noted from your comment.

The `MyBox` component code remains unchanged and still using `@bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex"` as required.

Working example:

```razor
@page "/"

<MudTabs @ref="tabs" Elevation="0" Outlined="true" 
         @bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex">
    <MudTabPanel Text="Red"></MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="Blue"></MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>

<MyBox colorBox="@((tabs == null) ? "Red": tabs?.Panels[activeIndex].Text)" />

@code
{
    private MudTabs? tabs;
    private int activeIndex = 0;
}
```

---

**Edit:**
If you want to run the method `SetColor` as mentioned in your comment, you then have to use `ActivePanelIndexChanged` to invoke this function whenever the panel index changes and assign the color.

However, you can't have `@bind-ActivePanelIndex="activeIndex"` and `ActivePanelIndexChanged` together in `MudTabs which will give the following error:

```
The component parameter 'ActivePanelIndexChanged' is used two or more times for this component.
```

Therefore, to bind index value to `activeIndex`, I modified the `SetColor` method to include a parameter which will pass the index of the panel from `ActivePanelIndexChanged`  EventCallback and assign it to `activeIndex`.

```razor
<MudTabs Elevation="0" Outlined="true"
        ActivePanelIndexChanged="@(index => SetColor(index))">
   <MudTabPanel Text="Red"></MudTabPanel>
   <MudTabPanel Text="Blue"></MudTabPanel>
</MudTabs>

<MyBox colorBox="@colorMe" />

@code
{
   private int activeIndex = 0;
   string colorMe = "red"; // specify default color of first panel

   void SetColor(int index)
   {
       activeIndex = index;

       if (activeIndex == 0)
       {
           colorMe = "red";
       }
       else if (activeIndex == 1)
       {
           colorMe = "blue";
       }
   }
}
```

---

Result:
[image: MudTabs change color on click]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually I need to run method "SetColor".

Comment: @Yurii.V. I editted my answer to include additional solution with using the `SetColor` method. If it answers you question, please do accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your function on tab click and provide your color as parameter to your function. For example:

```
<MudTabPanel Text="Red" OnClick="() => SetColor(YourParameter)"></MudTabPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me!
Is there any other variant to do this in case if I have 100500 <MudTabPanel> (just not to write "OnClick" for each tabs)?

Comment: You could specify an enum of Colors and genrate the code for the MudTabPanel with either a for or foreach loop.